# How to set a default value

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Here is how I extend the `Immutable.Record`

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const DATA_DEFAULTS = {
  id: String,
  data: String,
  ref_id: String,
};

export default class Data
  extends Immutable.Record(DATA_DEFAULTS) {}
```

If the json representation does not contain `ref_id`, then when I try to print the value of the field in the console of Chrome devtool, I will get:

```
> data.ref_id
String() { [native code] }
```

I think it is the reason why I cannot filter out entities with empty `ref_id` in a list

```
a = [] // a list of data
b = a.filter(x => x.ref_id != '')  // b is the same as a
```

I suppose it can be fixed by either:

- set a default value to a field in the `Immutable.Record` instance when the field is missing in the json data
- use another way to detect if the field is not set in the instance

For the second approach, I have tried, for example, `data.has('ref_id')` and it always report `true` regardless if the field has any valid value.

My questions:

1) Can I set a default value in a `Immutable.Record`?

2) How to filter on field that may or may not exist in the `Immutable.Record`

3) What is the right way to test the existence of valid value in a field in an instance of  `Immutable.Record`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the default values of each of the fields to the **function** `String`. `String` is not a data type here, if that's what you thought. What you seem to want is

```
const DATA_DEFAULTS = {
  id: '',
  data: '',
  ref_id: '',
};
```

---

> 1) Can I set a default value in a Immutable.Record?

Exactly how you already did, you just need to set the correct default value.

---

> 2) How to filter on field that may or may not exist in the Immutable.Record

Fields on a record always exist. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record):

> Records always have a value for the keys they define. removeing a key from a record simply resets it to the default value for that key.

---

> 3) What is the right way to test the existence of valid value in a field in an instance of `Immutable.Record`?

You can use a default value that you know would not be explicitly assigned to the field otherwise. That could be `null` or a symbol.